# Cypress.io and Cucumber.io testing integration, Step implementation missing for:

Tags: reactjs, cucumber, cypress

Integration of Cypress and Cucumber seem to go well, however when tests are executed I get the following error:

```
Step implementation missing for: I open login page
```

**cypress.json**

```
{
  "video": false,
  "baseUrl": "http://localhost:8080",
  "testFiles": "**/*.feature",
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true
  }
}
```

**./cypress/integration/login.feature**

```
Feature: Login Feature

  I want to login

  @focus
  Scenario: Navigate to Login
    Given I open login page
    Then I see Login
```

./cypress/integration/Login/login.js

```
import { Given, Then } from 'cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps';

Given( 'I open login page', () => cy.visit( '/Login' ) );

Then( 'Login page should be shown', () => cy.url().should( 'include', '/Login' ) );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **cypress-cucumber-preprocessor** config should go in **package.json**, not in **cypress.json**.

Also, I believe the step implementation folder name must match the feature file name. So you should rename your step implementation folder to **login** instead of Login (`./cypress/integration/login/login.js`)

See doc [here](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor#step-definitions-creation)

Comment: Step definitions should have the same name as your feature, that's just a best practice. So if you name it `helpers.js` (or whatever) that'll also work.

Answer (score 1):

Add **step_defintions** in your `package.json` with custom path

```
"cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
   "step_definitions": "cypress/integration/features/step_definitions/**/"
}
```

Comment: I missed `/**/`, thanks, it is working now.

Answer (score -1):

While I do not think this answer is ideal, I managed to get things working by removing `"cypress-cucumber-preprocessor"` from cypress.json and moving sub directories from the "cypress/integration" directory to "cypress/support/step_definitions"