# How to resolve Cypress Cucumber 'Step implementation missing for: ' error?

Tags: automated-tests, cucumber, cypress, bdd

I have set up Cypress Cucumber project as follows :

I have added  "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true in package-lock.json but still cannot find steps.

package-lock.json:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Bww37954Hy/

Feature File:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/SxmSkk2Hbv/

Step Defination File:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/k4x4NNypKf/

Directory Structure:

[Directory 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNdo2.png)

[Directory 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0mSJ.png)

Error log:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuwUY.png)

```
TEST BODY
1
When
go to AB site
2
then
{}, function(){}
Error
Step implementation missing for: go to AB site
node_modules/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/lib/resolveStepDefinition.js:195:1
  193 |       );
  194 |     }
> 195 |     throw new Error(`Step implementation missing for: ${stepText}`);
      | ^
  196 |   },
  197 |   Given: (...args) => {
  198 |     stepDefinitionRegistry.runtime(...args);


Stack:

  at Context.resolveAndRunStepDefinition (node_modules/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/lib/resolveStepDefinition.js:195:1)
at Context.eval (node_modules/cypress-cucumber-

preprocessor/lib/createTestFromScenario.js:26:1)
From previous event:
    at Context.thenFn (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:155135:24)
    at Context.then (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:155574:22)
    at Context.<anonymous> (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:169891:22)
    at <unknown> (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:169315:16)
From previous event:
    at runCommand (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:169294:9)
    at next (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:169440:15)
    at <unknown> (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:169468:17)
From previous event:
    at next (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:169440:35)
From previous event:
    at Promise.catch.err.name (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:169481:38)
From previous event:
    at run (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:169474:22)
    at $Cy.cy.<computed> [as then] (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:169931:12)
    at Context.runnable.fn (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:170155:22)
    at callFn (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:104227:22)
    at Test.../driver/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js.Runnable.run (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:104214:8)
    at <unknown> (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:175754:29)
From previous event:
    at Object.onRunnableRun (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:175742:18)
    at $Cypress.action (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:166291:29)
    at Test.Runnable.run (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:174128:14)
    at Runner.../driver/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js.Runner.runTest (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:104886:11)
    at <unknown> (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:105012:13)
    at next (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:104795:15)
    at <unknown> (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:104805:8)
    at next (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:104707:15)
    at Hook.<anonymous> (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:104768:8)
    at next (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:175675:23)
    at <unknown> (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:175697:12)
From previous event:
    at onNext (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:175694:58)
    at done (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:104167:6)
    at callFn (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:104250:8)
    at Hook.../driver/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js.Runnable.run (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:104214:8)
    at <unknown> (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:175754:29)
From previous event:
    at Object.onRunnableRun (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:175742:18)
    at $Cypress.action (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:166291:29)
    at Hook.Runnable.run (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:174128:14)
    at next (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:104729:11)
    at <unknown> (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:104773:6)
    at timeslice (http://localhost:33867/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:98699:28)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61050617/cypress-io-and-cucumber-io-testing-integration-step-implementation-missing-for

Answer (score 1):

You could try set the nonGlobalStepDefinitions as false and set the stepDefinitions folder

```
 "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": false,
    "stepDefinitions": "cypress/stepsDefinition"
  }
```