# Cypress-cucumber-preprocessor not running tests & error: "Step implementation missing for"

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Learner and keep getting "Step implementation missing for: I open Google page" error.

Here is my repo https://github.com/PatoDeVille/TsBDDtest.git

Checked the documentation here https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor#cypress-configuration and all seems okay.

The tutorial I am following is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZM7bzu0zIT8

Also checked the problem in [Cypress.io and Cucumber.io testing integration, Step implementation missing for:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61050617/cypress-io-and-cucumber-io-testing-integration-step-implementation-missing-for) and the bug is still present

**/package.json devDependencies**

```
{
    "browserify": "^16.2.3",
    "cypress": "^7.3.0",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.1.0",
    "node-static": "^0.7.11",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2"
  }
```

**/cypress.json**

```
{
    "testFiles": "**/*.feature"
}
```

**/.cypress-cucumber-preprocessorrc.json**

```
{
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true,
    "step_definitions": "cypress/support/step_definitions/"
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61050617/cypress-io-and-cucumber-io-testing-integration-step-implementation-missing-for

Comment: Thank you so so much!

Comment: Atul Kumar, i have already checked the other question but it did not fixed the bug

Answer (score 4):

If you specified in the following way

```
 "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true
  }
```

cypress will check for your test definitions inside the integration folder but if you want to change the location outsite the integration file folder you should set it as the following way (define the nonGlobalStepDefinitions as false and define the stepDefinitions file folder)

```
"cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": false,
    "stepDefinitions": "cypress/stepsDefinition"
  }
```

it should work, here I attach you an example of my structure

[image]